# Libre office calc trigger BASIC function using button

Tags: button, libreoffice, libreoffice-basic

I wrote a little BASIC function in libreoffice to get some sorting stuff done. Works nicely..

Now I want to trigger this function by pushing a button on the first sheet. I really don't get it working. I set a link to the basic function (Right-click on button -> Form -> Actions -> Then set the function at the correct action).

Libreoffice version: 4.0.4.2
OS: Ubuntu 12.10
Button-Type: "Schaltfläche" (German)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All I had to do, is to exit the "Entwurfsmodus" (German). I guess in English it is something like "design mode"... Then the link to the BASIC function works!

Comment: You may accept your own answer (this is completely ok on stackoverflow - see http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) so the issue is marked as solved.